# Ubuntu 18.04 - System freezes on black screen after waking from suspend

Tags: networking, 18.04, suspend, freeze

I've been having issues with my Lenovo Thinkpad P52s. About two weeks ago, I updated to windows 10 feature update 1903. Everything worked fine for about a week. I put my laptop to sleep as usual, but when I woke it up it was frozen. So I powered off and when I turned it back on everything windows related seemed to be corrupted. Even the recovery tool and a installation media I flashed onto a flash drive would freeze the system. 
Turns out it is an issue on Microsoft's part.

Because I need this laptop for school, I wiped the hard drive and installed Ubuntu. Ubuntu runs good enough for me except for two problems. The first problem isn't too big, but I am able to connect to ethernet and wifi, but hidden networks give an activation network. When the hidden network is unhidden it connects, but fails to as soon as it is put back hidden.

The second problem is what I really need fixed. When the laptop is put into suspend, it works fine, but when trying to wake the laptop, it will turn back on but the screen stays blank and everything eventually just freezes. I would like to figure out how to suspend and wake my laptop normally as I need it for doing schoolwork.

I don't have any system info listed, but if anyone has an idea of where to start, let me know what information you need to help me. I'm hoping this is not a BIOS issue and something I can just fix within Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a common driver issue, lots of question has been posted on the subject. Check out posts like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen-remains-blank-after-wake-up-from-suspend).

Comment: The waking up from suspension issue is likely related with graphics drivers. If you have Nvidia then you should install proprietary Nvidia drivers. But considering how fast current hardware boots and shuts down, do you really need suspending it all the time? I rarely if ever do that.

Comment: I have actually tried testing the driver issues before posting. I switched my nvidia driver from x.org to the nvidia-driver-430. It does not fix the issue. My system also has built in intel graphics, so I tried using that as well but it did not solve it. The issue happens after the computer goes to suspend, it wakes up but freezes.

Comment: I don't really need suspend fixed, but I need a way of saving where I left off, say I have chrome open and need to head out to class, I need to be able to open the laptop and continue to use chrome. Currently, my laptop freezes whenever I open it after being closed forcing me to turn it off.

Comment: @SolomonDenning I recommend you edit your question to include all this information.