# Screen blank on waking from suspend

Tags: suspend, screen

Running Ubuntu 18.04 on a laptop that used to run Windows 10. These are the laptop specs, if applicable:

```
Acer Aspire
Memory 3.4 GiB
Processor: AMD® Ryzen 3 3200u with radeon vega mobile gfx × 4 
Graphics: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 128 bits)
Gnome: 3.28.1
OS type: 64-bit
Disk: 125.2 GB
```

So the issue I am having is that the whenever I suspend the laptop, pushing a key or clicking the track pad will bring it out of suspend, but the screen will stay off. I know it comes out of suspend because the power indicator will flash from orange to blue, and  I become able to turn the backlight on or off, or even change the volume. I can hear it happening, I just can't see anything. [18.04 Screen remains blank after wake up from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen-remains-blank-after-wake-up-from-suspend) is an almost an identical issue, but none of the solutions work on my end ("nouveau.modeset=0" not found). I think the issue might be an incompatible graphics card, but since it is a brand new laptop, I am hoping I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved with the update to Ubuntu 19.10.Pretty sure llvmpipe is just not compatible with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: There is no such release as Ubuntu 19.01  (or the 2019-January release of Ubuntu).  Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format for standard desktop & server releases, with a small number of specialist (*snap* only) releases use the *year* format only. Did you mean the 2019-October release (ie. 19.10)?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant.