# Ubuntu 19.10 Screen remains blank after wake up from suspend

Tags: suspend, screen, wakeup

After the screen went blanc, it will intermittently not give a login prompt when you wake the screen.

I have Ubuntu 19.10 installed on a Dell Vostro 3670 (Intel® Core™ i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 12 ). The system has a Nvidia video card and the Nvidia 435.21 driver is installed.

I found a potential solution for Unbutu 18 ([18.04 Screen remains blank after wake up from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen-remains-blank-after-wake-up-from-suspend)):

$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

(change line to - GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0")

$ sudo update-grub

This did not work. Any other solution?
Best wishes, Gert Kruger

Comment: nouveau.modeset=0 won't work for your Nvidia card. Try changing your /etc/default/grub file to... find "quiet splash" change to "quiet splash nomodeset", then `sudo update-grub`. This change should be considered temporary, and only for testing. Your screen resolution may be messed up during this test.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this.  It still gives the same issue.  Any other suggestion?

Comment: Is your video set to use the Intel video card or the Nvidia video card? What model Nvidia card? Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. In `Software & Updates`, Additional Drivers tab, tell me what you see... probably easier in a screenshot... load it to imgur.com if you don't know how to add it to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  When I use $ lspci | grep VGA I get the following output:

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] (rev a1)

Bios version: 2.13.0

Additional drivers: NVIDIA Corporation: GP107 {GeForce GTX 1050].  Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-435.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've put together a quick answer as a place to start. Either one could fix your problem. Report back.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with:

**BIOS**:

Your BIOS is 2.13.0. Current BIOS is 2.14.0, from Nov 26, 2019.

Please see https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=yh9x7 for the update.

Please see https://www.dell.com/support/article/za/en/zabsdt1/sln171755/update-the-dell-bios-in-a-linux-or-ubuntu-environment?lang=en for how to do this in a Linux only environment.

**NVIDIA**:

Your Nvidia driver is 435.21. Current driver is 440.44, from Dec 11, 2019.

Please see https://www.geforce.com/drivers for the update.

Comment: Thanks!  I managed to do both and after about 2 days I have not observed the same blank screen issue.

It was a bit challenging to update the bios as one don't get a Linux option to download.  I followed the instructions from https://www.dell.com/support/article/za/en/zabsdt1/sln171755/update-the-dell-bios-in-a-linux-or-ubuntu-environment?lang=en 

and just copied the Windows bios exe file on a flashdisk.  Thanks a lot!
Gert Kruger

Comment: @GertKruger Great news! Please remember to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons just to the left of my answer. Thanks!