# Problem With Black Screen When Attempting to Resume After my Laptop Hibernates

Tags: suspend, hibernate, resume

My problem was experienced by several Ubuntu users a few years ago.

The difference is that I'm running the latest Ubuntu operating system (19.10).[image]

I ran with Ubuntu 18.04 Disco Dingo about 1.5 yrs ago; and upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04 about 6 months ago.  Never had this problem with both O/S versions using the same laptop (Lenovo ideapad 320).

The problem started about a month ago.

What is the solution to my problem ?

Comment: Hi da_kingpin.  Unfortunately I'm not a programmer or IT specialist....so I can't appreciate your advice ..... I just don't have the knowledge.   But thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, if you can't login you can login to tty using ctrl+shift+f2
Then 
Use this command

```
sudo loginctl list-sessions
```

To get your current session
Then unlock it using this command

```
sudo loginctl unlock-session {session-id}
```

Comment: Hi Yasien.  When my laptop screen 'switches on', then I am able to log in - no problem.   My problem is that my screen remains black (off) whenever my laptop has been hibernating.  Sometimes it comes alive after pressing the Enter key about 20 times or the Esc key about 20 times or the Spacebar key 20 times .... but this only happens sometimes.   More often than not I have switch off my laptop (using the Power button)....and then re-boot it.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry if my answer didn't make sense to you.
You can check answers to this question as I guess they are addressing the same issue
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen-remains-blank-after-wake-up-from-suspend

Answer (score 0):

After several weeks of frustration, trying to get my laptop to resume after a Suspend/Hibernate period; and after posting my problem on Ask Ubuntu - I stumbled on a VERY SIMPLE solution !   Maybe not the 'technically correct' solution - but a solution that works very well - nonetheless.

The GNOME Tweaks Tool, which I loaded with Ubuntu 18.04 and again 19.04, has an option to disable/enable the option "Suspend when laptop lid is closed" (under General in the Tweaks menu).  I set it to the 'off position' .... and it works perfectly - for me !!

So, when I'm done with my activities on my laptop, I simply close the lid and the screen switches off just before the lid is completely closed.  Then when I open the lid (after 1 or 10 or 30 mins or 1 hr) the screen comes back to life, as I left it before closing the lid.

Alternatively, if I first log out before closing the lid, I get the same good result - and when I open the lid, I just type in my password on the login screen.

I'm HAPPY !!!!