# 19.10 Screen remains black after wake up from suspend - Asus Zenbook

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend, asus, 19.10

I have exactly the same issue which was asked in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen-remains-blank-after-wake-up-from-suspend) thread: the screen remains black when I open my laptop after suspending it; I can not see anything but I can turn up and down the volume with the keyboard. However, none of the proposed solutions worked for me.

Here I will attach some more information:

- **Computer:** Asus Zenbook Pro 15 UX580GD
- **OS:** Ubuntu 19.10 dualboot with W10
- **BIOS version:** UX550GDX.308
- **Graphic card:** NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
- **Driver in use:** NVIDIA metapackage from nvidia-driver-440
- **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX:** "nouveau.modeset=0 nomodeset"

Tell me what additional information or command output is needed to spot the problem, becuase I suppose this is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I had one problem with one of my ppa dependencies and `sudo-apt update` was actually not doing anything.

1. Remove the ppa dependency which was causing the problem going to "Software and updates" > "Other software" and unchecking it.
2. Run `sudo apt-get update` and see if it is now actually doing the updates
3. Update drivers by opening the "Updates" program which comes with Linux
4. Change the driver in use going to "Software and updates" > "More drivers" and select the "X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver"
5. Change the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to "nouveau.modeset=0" (without nomodeset, that was what was causing the problem, this way we only run on nomodeset the nouveau driver)
6. Run `sudo update-grub` and reboot

That's it, this worked for me perfectly and I have not experienced the same problem since then.