# Black screen right after attempting shutdown, suspend or log off, requiring hard reboot

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, shutdown, logout

I have a Kubuntu 20.04 installed on its own drive, with an attached Windows 10 installation, using a GTX 1050 TI laptop card.

There are no issues booting from an already shut down computer, but if I attempt to shut down, suspend or log off I am brought to a black screen with a _ cursor in the upper left corner that I cannot recover from using `CTRL` `ALT` `F1` or `F7`. After a hard reset I can log in normally with no error messages.

I've tried applying [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041397) to no avail, but it appears to be an issue with entering suspension rather than waking from it. Is there a way I can open the console to at least diagnose the issue?