# Kubuntu 20.04 Black Screen After Sleep

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, suspend, 20.04, hp

This is an issue I have been trying to fix for a while now, I am running Kubuntu 20.04 and whenever I put my laptop to sleep or close the lid and try to wake it up again the LED's at the back of the screen turn on (as well as the fans), but there is no login screen.
I have to then manually shut down my laptop then restart it, go through the GRUB menu, select Kubuntu and then go to the login screen

My laptop = Hp Laptop 15-db0xxx (Ryzen 5 2500u with Radeon Vega 8 Moblie Graphics)

I have also tried implementing the solutions below but they did not work:

[18.04 Screen remains blank after wake up from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen-remains-blank-after-wake-up-from-suspend)

https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/f58f2w/kubuntu_1910_black_screen_after_sleep/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FINALLY FOUND THE SOLUTION !!!

So I changed from Kubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I still had the same problem of the screen's LED's turning on but the screen remaining black and not showing the login screen after I had turned my laptop on from sleep mode.

SOLUTION:

I had to change the boot order of the OS in my BIOS, originally Windows was put first then it was Ubuntu/Kubuntu so I had to change it so Ubuntu/Kubuntu would be first and Windows was second!

I tested this on Ubuntu, but I am pretty sure that this should work on Kubuntu if your boot order has Windows first!

I hope this will help anybody else who has had this issue or one that is similar!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, running Kubuntu 20.04 with 2 users configuration, on 2nd user after running a game I will have a black or frozeen scren after wakeup. On the old days Kubuntu had by default configured a hot key sequence to kill the X server Ctrl+Alt+backspace. I activated the hotkey sequence in system settings and it works for me. Go to System Settings,Hardware, Input Devices, Keyboard, advance, find "key sequence to kill X server" and select Ctrl+Alt+backspace. Hope this work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I have Same Problem I Use Kubuntu 20.04.1 before, and i get bad error and i should reinstall kubuntu i install kubuntu 20.04.2 and get this error (cant suspend or hibrenate) i search in internet and found its nvidia driver problem but i didnt found how fix that, i make my solution, my kubuntu default install nvidia 460 version its ubuntu recommended i purge (`sudo apt purge nvidia*`) that and install nvidia-driver-450 (`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450`) and after that i got blackscreen on bootup, after that i purge nvidia-450 and install again `nvidia-driver-460` and i suprise my problem fixed :)
i hope help you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by changing default GPU to Intel build-in GPU inside `NVIDIA X Server Setting` app and now everything is ok.