# 20.04 - Sometimes unable to wake from suspend, and touchpad not working after waking from suspend

Tags: dual-boot, suspend, touchpad

I am running a dual booted windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04 with standard GNOME interface on a huawei matebook 14 D, which uses an AMD ryzen 5. I have been experiencing some strange problems surrounding automatically suspending/screen locking. The first one is that occasionally the screen remains black when I try to wake up the laptop, this is only resolvable by rebooting by holding down power button. This has most recently occurred when the laptop was left open and allowed to suspend automatically. The backlight and fans turn on as they should when a key is pressed but not the screen.

I have seen this thread: [Kubuntu 20.04 Black Screen After Sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247510/kubuntu-20-04-black-screen-after-sleep) suggesting I change the boot order to set the ubuntu disk first, but my dual boot is on a single partitioned drive, and my BIOS, InsydeH20 does not have boot order settings, just enable/disable drives.

Another, possibly related and more frequent issue is that after waking from suspend, the touchpad works for around 2 seconds, then stops working and also can only be resolved with a reboot. I think but am not sure that I am using the synaptics input drivers, as the stock drivers were not working well, if someone could suggest how I identify the current touchpad driver I will let them know!

Interestingly and frustratingly I have been unable to replicate the problem by suspending from the power menu in ubuntu, I wonder if low-level/bios power settings that are activating are some period of inactivity are interfering with ubuntu.

Any advice on how to investigate this problem further would be most welcome

Thanks