# Black screen after waking from suspend on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, suspend, gdm, amd-processor

I am very new to linux. On my laptop I have a multiboot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 on the same disk.

The problem is when I suspend to RAM and then wake it up by pressing the power button, the disk starts running, however **the screen remains black**. I tried logging in blind (the screen was still black and I tried using the keyboard), opening terminal and typing `reboot` and that works.

Looking for solution, I found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen-remains-blank-after-wake-up-from-suspend#comment2067311_1041397). One of the solutions were to `sudoedit /etc/default/grub` and add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the line that says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. Apparently it's an nvidia driver bug. Except I have AMD CPU with Radeon graphics, so this isn't my case, right?

Another solution was installing `xscreensaver`, which I already had installed. I also checked the possibility of having the swap partition encrypted which also wasn't the case.

Is it some problem with AMD drivers? Can you please help me find a solution?

My hardware is HP Probook 455 G7 with AMD Ryzen 3 4300U, AMD Radeon Graphics and 16 GB RAM. I am running 64bit Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, GNOME 3.36.3 and kernel 5.4.0-47

Comment: Wake is always difficult in linux... You should seach in Google if something wrote some about your computer with some suspend, wake,...  and your comuter name keywords.

Comment: All these answers about Nvidia when OP clearly states they're using AMD.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like an amdgpu issue, which is resolved in kernel 5.8. As the current kernel is 5.4, you should do:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge
```

I found the answer here: [Is there a kernel 5.8 ppa for ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291655/is-there-a-kernel-5-8-ppa-for-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: I use kernel 5.8 and I am facing this issue too

Comment: 5.10 and same problem...

Comment: 5.11 and same problem.

Comment: Kernel 5.13.0-37 AMD CPU, same problem
Once monitor is going to sleep (or disconnected or turned off), only a full reboot revives it.

Comment: 5.15.0-46 same thing. I'm having to reboot.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this post and have an Nvidia card.  The `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` fixed the issue for me.

So for anyone with Nvidia cards, it seems that clicking on 'additional drivers' doesn't have what an `autoinstall` does.

Update: Yes the above fixed if one has Nivida and same blank screen after suspend, yet found issue remain if logged in, and suspend resumed as normal if I logged out first then suspend.  Then resume normal.  Strange.

For debugging I use to have separate home partition and swap partition and all this now since found do not need seaparate partitions.  Anyway found another post suggested:

...
sudo apt install gnome-screensaver
...

Now No more blank screen after suspend resume.  So an easy fix:

...
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall && apt install gnome-screensaver
...

p.s. I think it is to do with 'no-more' separate swap and root partitions, and current Nvidia video drivers. not technical so just saying.  Thank you all at ask Ubuntu, posting this for others.  Happy puppy :-)

Comment: As [noted yesterday](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275093/black-screen-after-waking-from-suspend-on-ubuntu-20-04/1355647#comment2319817_1354056), `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` is for proprietary drivers, such as Nvidia's. However the OP has AMD graphics, which require open source drivers.

Comment: seems the title of this question is causing people with other graphics hardware to land on this question. Answers like this can be here to help them I guess

Answer (score 2):

On my Legion 5 pro with NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050Ti this solution works for me (It fixes both issues: change brightness and wake up after suspend)

0. Select `discrete card` in BIOS setup
1. Install drivers

```
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

2. Open Software & Updates application on tab Additional drivers select `nvidia-driver-470`, it does not works with `nvidia-driver-510`

Restart system

3. Go to `/sys/class/backlight` and get available brightness acpi

```sh
> ls /sys/class/backlight
nvidia_0    # <- if you have here nvidia_0 then it's ok
```

4. Create backlight rule

```sh
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/backlight.rules
```

add this content

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", KERNEL=="nvidia_0", GROUP="video", MODE="0664"
RUN+="/bin/chgrp video /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness"
RUN+="/bin/chmod g+w /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness"
```

Save file

5. Update grub

```sh
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

update line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=nvidia_0 nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

save file

```sh
sudo update-grub
```

Restart system

Comment: Amazing. Tried every possible combination from other answers and nothing helped. It works in Ubuntu 21.10, Lenovo Legion 7 RTX 3070

Comment: Finally this worked. `nvidia-driver-470` proved to be the key. For brightness I found that the backlight rule could be skipped.

Comment: What if the directory `/sys/class/backlight` is empty after switching to the `nvidia-driver-470`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can come from GPU drivers.
Try this one, then restart your laptop:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Comment: Not applicable. `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` is only for **proprietary** drivers. AMD graphics drivers are open/source.

Comment: Not applicable to this question yes, but it did solve this same issue I had in my box with an NVIDIA card. Thanks @Walllter .

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that I have issues coming back from suspend if the video driver and line 11 of /etc/default/grub do not correlate to the following:

if using the NVIDIA proprietary driver go into /etc/default/grub and change line 11 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

if using the X.org driver go into /etc/default/grub and change line 11 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"

After making the change depending on which driver I'm using it has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if using the NVIDIA proprietary driver go into /etc/default/grub and change line 11 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

if using the X.org driver go into /etc/default/grub and change line 11 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"

and... You need to check the settings of the NVIDIA driver!!!
Mine was on balanced and nothing helped until I changed to the FullPower-NVIDIA or the Powersaving Xorg driver...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Thanks for posting an answer. Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer). Also, see https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting