# Laptop not waking up from suspend on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: suspend

Whenever I put my laptop to suspend and then try to wake it up after some time (short or long) the keyboard backlight turns on but the laptop screen does not, from here I can only force power off and then restart.
I found some people who were facing the same issue, but they were able to fix it by editing some line in gdm3, but that was a nvidia graphic driver bug and my laptop only has integrated iris xe graphics. Please tell what to do

I have i5 11th gen processor with integrated graphics

Comment: Any 10th or 11th gen CPU/GPU is better supported with kernels newer than the one shipped with 20.04. It's always a bad idea to use a release older than the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I'm not to sure what it could be, however it might be a driver graphics driver issue. I found this thread, it might help you. Try some solutions in here. [Black screen after waking from suspend on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275093/black-screen-after-waking-from-suspend-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Best of luck