# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't wake up after suspend or restart

Tags: boot, 20.04, nvidia, suspend, restart

I just got a new PC and installed Ubuntu on it, which I'm completely new to (literally installed 3 days ago). I just found out that when I try to either restart or suspend the PC it turns into a black screen that doesn't respond.

I found a lot of similar questions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298198/ubuntu-20-04-doesnt-wake-up-after-suspend) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275093/black-screen-after-waking-from-suspend-on-ubuntu-20-04) but they seem to only focus on suspend and my problem seems to also be when I restart, so I wasn't sure if they are related. I tried following the second link and ran `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall && apt install gnome-screensaver` but that didn't seem help.

As I'm completely new in this community I'm not sure what details to add, but my CPU is
`AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core 3.7GHz` and GPU `Nvidia GeForce RTX™ 3090`. When I go to `software & updates / additional drivers` it seems like it's on `nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary, tested)`. I tried switching to `nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary)`, to `nvidia-driver-460 (proprietary)`, or to `X.Org server`, but nothing worked.

Running `nvidia-smi` I get:
`NVIDIA-SMI 470.86       Driver Version: 470.86       CUDA Version: 11.4`

Please do let me know if there is any other information needed to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like after trying various things only changing the driver to 495 from 470 worked. There might be another solution but this seems to solve it (while apparently not breaking anything else)