# Stuck at black screen after waking up from suspension

Tags: 20.04, suspend

I have ubuntu 20.04 running on asus rog 14. When I try to wake it up from the suspension the screen remains black. No matter what I do it won't open the screen.

I have tried everything mentioned in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen-remains-blank-after-wake-up-from-suspend). But still, the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by updating the kernel to 5.9.5 from 5.4. Works fine.