# Suspend doesn't work | Dell Inspiron 3593 | Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, suspend, dell

I have bought a new Dell Inspiron 3593 and have loaded it with ubuntu 20.04 parallel to the stock windows. However, the suspend function is not working for the laptop. Whenever I suspend the laptop and try to wake it, the screen stays blank although I see my USB keyboard working. I have to force shut down the laptop and restart it to resume working. Kindly help!!

As I am unaware of what might be causing the problem, I am not posting any details of my ubuntu installation or the hardware. I will readily provide them if required

Thanking You in advance  :)

**Update:**

I have found this: https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-dell-latitude-7390-ubuntu-20-04-sometimes-hangs-and-reboot-after-pressing-suspend/

and this: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/doesnt-wake-up-from-sleep-mode/13830

One of the posts asks to make changes in the grub and blacklist.
I am (1) unaware of how to make those changes
(2) scared that I might break the installation by doing things that I don't really know

Comment: @Quasímodo, Hi I have updated the question with what I had found earlier, Someone had suggested installing KDE-plasma, and I tried that and created havoc in my laptop. I had to reinstall lightdm and gnome-desktop to be able to login back to my account normally. So I don't want to do anything stupid anymore. Kindly help !!

Comment: Give https://askubuntu.com/q/1032633 a try

Comment: @Quasímodo.  I just tried that. The laptop won't wake up from suspend.  And I had to force restart