# Ubuntu shows blank screen after waking up from suspend (dual boot)

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, suspend

I have a dual boot system. When my ubuntu suspends, after waking up it shows a blank screen; I've tried multiple solutions but wasn't helpful. :(
This is my ubuntu description:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Does anybody know what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

More info on your system is needed.
I will post a few commands to help with this.
Plus a few tentative solutions.

### Additional info on your system

Please post, by exactly copy-pasting both the commands you enter and the output you get of the following:

```
$ uname -a
$ inxi -Fxxxz
$ lspci -knn | grep -EA4 'VGA|3D|Display'
$ hwinfo --gfxcard
$ neofetch
```

You might need

```
$ sudo apt install inxi hwinfo neofetch
```

### Possible solutions

1. Configure driver options at boot time. For instance, if using the `noveau` driver, add `modeset=0`. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041397/226614). I will wait for your further info.
2. Ctrl+Alt+F3 and back with Ctrl+Alt+F2, as a [temporary solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1032636/226614).
3. Updating graphics driver.
4. Try with `sudo systemctl suspend`, and then waking up. See [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2443153).
5. Try with `sudo pm-suspend`, and then waking up.

### Related

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442057/ubuntu-18-04-wont-wake-after-screen-lock-and-blank-suspend-sleep

Comment: I updated the information :) in addition, I tried all solutions above but wasn't helpful.

Comment: @ShirinJZ - I will check. Please consider copy-pasting as (markdown formatted) text, not screen captures.
That is essential for further searching. It makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: thank you, I will update it :)