# Getting suspend to work on Ubuntu (21.10 - impish release)?

Tags: boot, system-installation, suspend, secure-boot, 21.10

I turned off secure boot and installed ubuntu.

Everything was wiped and installation went fine.

I am using an aero 15x v8 laptop. Version 21.10 of Ubuntu.

Then I turned secure boot back on but it doesn't resume after I suspend (close the lid, or it idles for too long).

I'm not sure how to fix it.

I bought a book on linux but it is 500 pages and it will take me some time to get through it.

Is there something I missed?

Comment: You missed https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnderstandingSuspend

Comment: And https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate

Comment: And: [How to enable hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation)

Comment: Is suspend not working *only* after secure boot is turned on? In other words, does it work correctly with secure boot turned on? Make that very clear in your question. If that is the case, the workaround is easy: keep secure boot turned off.

Comment: Also try nuking NVIDIA: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen-remains-blank-after-wake-up-from-suspend/1391917#1391917