# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS can not wake up from suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management

I have an ASUS UX461U which originally had Windows 10 installed. When it was still installed, I dropped it and it couldn't wake up from sleep anymore. I installed Ubuntu recently and the problem seems to have carried over to its suspend mode with no particular reason.

Things I've tried:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to turn screen back on ([link to solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1032636/1587373))
- Soft rebooting ([link to solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1286455/1587373))

Other info:

- OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- GNOME Version: 3.36.8
- Processor:
- Graphics: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)