# Screen stays black after waking up from suspend mode

Tags: suspend, 22.04

The screen stays black when I put my laptop into suspend mode and then wake it up again.
None of the solutions I've seen so far have worked for me.

what I have tried/read:
So far I have mainly tried to change the parameters GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in the grub file because this was mentioned as a solution in existing articles on the problem, e.g. in this article [18.04 Screen remains blank after wake up from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen). Mainly the problem seems to occur with Nvidia users as I have seen it in various stackexchange and reddit forums (due to a driver error). Since I'm not an Nvidia user, I ruled out this problem. All forum posts recommended setting GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX = nouveau.modeset=0" as the best solution, but when I opened my grub file I saw that this is already the default setting in my grub file (I've never touched my grub file before ).
So since this wasn't a solution, I read in an article (which I, unfortunately, can't find anymore) that I should try to set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX = blacklist=1 as an alternative (to be honest I don't really know what to do with it) which unfortunately didn't help.

Thanks for your help

Here is my grub file(/etc/default/grub) and my system information.

[image]

[image: my system]

Comment: what I did is prevent my laptop (lenovo ideapad 5) from suspend, I just don't want to restart my pc after every break. sorry probably not the answer you're looking for, I hope someone can answer this with real solution

Comment: Have you tried installing, the Graphics drivers for your GPU?