# no display in ubuntu after it goes to sleep or monitor lid closed

Tags: 20.04, display, laptop, intel-graphics, amd-graphics

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my HP Pavilion G series laptop. I have a problem that whenever I close lid of my laptop or laptop goes to sleep, there is no display after lid is reopened or keys are pressed to wake up the laptop.

---

I tried reinstalling the OS but the problem is still there as it is.

---

i also tried following steps from this guide [18.04 Screen remains blank after wake up from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen-remains-blank-after-wake-up-from-suspend) . It didnt worked too

$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

Then adding nouveau.modeset=0 to the line that says GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX.

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"$ sudo update-grub

reboot

---

When I execute systemctl suspend the LED goes to sleep but no display appears when I press any key.

---

$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]

---

can anyone help ???

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings of variable **HandleLidSwitch** in */etc/systemd/logind.conf*, your options are:

- lock
- ignore
- poweroff
- hibernate

Once you set it to your desired behaviour you need to restart the service:

***systemctl restart systemd-logind.service***