Screen blanking after a few minutes even with input
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS -
The single monitor connected to the device blanks after a few minutes and only fixes itself after a restart. The monitor shows a "No Input" during each of these blanks.
I already tried switching out the cable and plugging it back in, but the monitor would not turn on again. The monitor blanking happens regardless of activity, I could be in the middle of typing something and it would blank.
Using Ctrl + Alt + F3, and Ctrl + Alt + F2/F7 didn't change anything (https://askubuntu.com/a/1032636), I also tried editing the grub (https://askubuntu.com/a/1041397) to no avail. Using any sort of xwindow command didn't work either since I can only access the device through SSH. Specifying -display :0.0 just hung the terminal indefinitely.
All auto-blank display settings are set to never, and this wouldn't even make sense since the screen blanks even with input. All drivers should be up to date.
EDIT: The device remains operational through SSH and responds successfully to any requests made to services run by the device. Additionally, even using RDP to access the device will result in a blank screen.
Device Specs
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS 
Intel i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz 
16 GB RAM 
NVIDIA GeForce GT 730

Wasn't able to get it working, so I switched to a spare 1070 I had lying around.
