Ubuntu 24.04 won't wake from suspend
My computer will not wake from suspend. Anytime I try to wake it from suspend (whether the system was manually or automatically put into suspend), it doesn't display anything. The only signs of life from my computer are the fans are spinning and my keyboard lights turn on. I have to hit the reset switch on my computer in order to see anything.
I'm not sure what else to do, I tried switching drivers from Nvidia drivers to Nouveau drivers and I still have the same issue.
I would love if anyone can help me with this issue, and I'd be happy to provide system logs if requested (I don't know where to find them).
I also would like to continue using suspend, rather than just disabling automatic suspend.

Have you found solution? I have same issue. It was solved in 22.04 by this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633. However after upgrade to 24.04, issue is resurrected for me unfortunately.
