# After upgrading from 17.10 Ubuntu 18.04 won't sleep/suspend

Tags: upgrade, suspend, 18.04

Today I upgraded Ubuntu from 17.10 to 18.04 and can't figure out what's going on. When I click suspend button display becomes black but laptop is still running. I already tried many things like editing logind.conf and acpi-support files but nothing same old same old. Help me

Comment: Sometimes you can suspend via menu, when it doesn't work by closing lid. You can look for messages using `journalctl -b | grep sleep` and `journalctl -b | grep suspend`. Linux is infamous for suspend/resume problems and with laptops in general. Still for all it's warts it beats Windows amongst enthusiasts albiet not for business and finance.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing what appears to be this very same issue with an HP Pavilion 11 x360.

I have installed Ubuntu and Kubuntu 18.04 a couple of times on my friend's and my own laptops without any suspend issues, but this one *'problem child'* has been very much misbehaving.

The Pavilion goes to a black screen but the power LED stays on and the fan continues to spin (if it had been doing so already). The laptop remains unresponsive to anything until I shut it down.

It has done this with both Ubuntu and Kubuntu 18.04 but worked fine with Ubuntu and Kubuntu 17.10.

---

**Edit - There are a few issues that look similar - an nVidia graphics driver problem, the machine going into s2idle instead of suspend and this specific issue that seems to only be affecting a small number of people. Take a look at the steps here to help identify your issue:** [Ubuntu 18.04 - Dell XPS13 9370 no longer suspends on lid close](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close/1044270#1044270)

---

It doesn't seem to be affecting everyone (otherwise I assume it'd be all over the forums by now) but after trying things like pm-utils and adjusting grub configurations to no avail, I found this answer from **matalak**'s question:

[Ubuntu 18.04 crashes on resuming from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029405/ubuntu-18-04-crashes-on-resuming-from-suspend)

Following the suggestion, I used **UKUU** to install an older kernel (4.14.47 - the most up to date 4.14 kernel) and suspend worked again as it should.

---

**Edit -** *If you have **nVidia graphics**, there seems to be a fix that is working for a number of people, helpfully provided by **cascagrossa** in the answer to the question linked above.*

A bug report has been opened https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1774950 and there is a patch that resolves the issue, so the suspend problem should be fixed in an update in the near future.

---

Using an older kernel is only a temporary solution and I'd quite like to be using 4.15 and onwards (4.16 and 4.17 and had the same suspend problems when i tried them out)..

**Could you also add what machine you are using to your question?**

**Can you let us know if trying the 4.14 kernel lets suspend work as normal for you too?**