# Ubuntu 18.04 Bluetooth and Wireless soft-blocked after restarts

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I upgraded recently from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 on my HP spectre laptop. Among a lot of other problems, there is the annoying behavior that Bluetooth and WiFi are both soft-blocked after a restart.
`rfkill list` produces

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

While I am able to turn on Wireless, nothing happens, when I toggle the Bluetooth switch.
I can enable both with `rfkill unblock all`, but at the next startup both are soft-blocked again. Additionally, if I unblock both, Bluetooth is turned on, but now I can't turn it off anymore. Not sure, if this is related, but I also don't have the usual Bluetooth icon in the tray area, although I was able to revive all other icons after the upgrade.
Is there any long-term solution for this problem?

If any additional hardware/software information is required, please ask.

P.S.: I have seen [this permanent solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047455/757139), but under `/etc/default`I did not find any file `tlp` to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Since there were a lot of other problems with GNOME apart from this one (e.g., [suspend wasn't working](https://askubuntu.com/q/1041369/757139), icons didn't appear), I use again UNITY instead of GNOME. It is easy - during login, you can choose. There is a little cog wheel next to "Sign-In" that allows you to select "Unity", "Ubuntu (Gnome)", "Ubuntu on Wayland", or "Plasma (KDE)".

**Update**
After updating to 20.04, I had problems with Unity (the taskbar was not working properly, the search function did not retrieve any files/programs), so I gave Gnome a second chance. Et voila, this time, everything worked out-of-the-box.