# Unable to use laptop after I close and open the lid

Tags: nvidia, kernel, wakeup, lid

After closing the lid on my laptop (using all default settings) and opening it again, I am unable to use it and have to reboot it.
[image: Image of error]

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.
Is there anything I could do to resolve this?

If you can’t read the error, here it is:

```
[201.360463] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 32, Channel ID 00000000 intr 80040000
```

I am using NVIDIA MX150, with driver version 390.48.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please post the image with readable text (also [cut out](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000989.htm) the blank area) or even better, transcribe the shown text directly to your question. What hardware do you use? Do you have Nvidia graphics (related https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1163786)? Can you switch to a [virtual terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33078/what-is-a-virtual-terminal-for) when the error appears?

Answer (score 0):

Install gnome tweaks from:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Launch it, head to power section and set the "suspend when laptop lid is closed" button off.

Comment: I use gnome tweaks only for font size, but i dont want the PC to still be running after closing the lid. I want it to "sleep" and when i open the laptop i want to be prompted with normal login screen

Comment: It might be an incompatibility with the hardware in later kernel versions, Try installing [Ukuu] (https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu) and downgrading kernel to 4.14.41.

Comment: Here is the original post marked as solved https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029405/ubuntu-18-04-crashes-on-resuming-from-suspend

Comment: Karnel v 4.14.41 did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @AleksandarKostovic I’m glad you solved your problem! Won’t you post an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer)?