# Pc goes stand by and I can't use it anymore

Tags: intel-graphics, standby

I just installed the latest desktop version of ubuntu 22.04 LTS jammy (I installed it next to the windows OS) and I'm running into this problem: everytime the computer goes on stand-by, he never wakes up. I have to turn it off by force (pressing the power button) and then restart from the beginning..

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078758/computer-goes-into-sleep-mode-but-wont-wake-up) about this topic but I would kindly prefer if someone would check what I need to do before doing something wrong, since the version of ubuntu has changed and also my pc is different.

Here I copy some details (obtained using lshw command) of the computer I'm having troubles with:

- description: Notebook
- product: Inspiron 16 5620 (0B3B)
- vendor: Dell Inc.

---

- cpu
- product: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1255U
- vendor: Intel Corp.

---

- display
- description: VGA compatible controller
- product: Intel Corporation
  vendor: Intel Corporation

(it should be an intel graphics iris xe but it is not written anywhere)

Comment: Proper support for Intel's 12th gen CPUs is in the works. You may have to wait for a newer kernel.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but what kernel you are referring to? At the moment I solved this problem installing the linux oem (I'm not really sure what it is)  with the command `sudo apt install linux-oem-22.04`. Now it works properly but using `inxi -G` I get that I'm using as graphics "Intel driver: i915 v: kernel". Is this correct or not?

Comment: OEM kernels often provide hardware support that is absent from the regular versions.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Then so far what I did is good, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, of course :)