# DELL XPS 13 with ubuntu 18.04 Suspend Freezes

Tags: kernel, suspend, dell

Under Ubuntu and any kernel, 4.x Laptop become unresponsive with a black screen after any suspend event (lid closed, suspend command, etc)

I just bought the new XPS Signature Edition 13 and installed Ubuntu 18.04, I tried many of the forums answers including changing the kernel version with Ukuu,

This is the description of my hardware:

```
System:    Host: talos Kernel: 4.17.14-041714-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 8.2.0 Console: tty 0
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Dell product: XPS 13 9360 serial: <filter>
           Mobo: Dell model: 0839Y6 v: A00 serial: <filter> UEFI: Dell v: 1.0.0 date: 07/31/2016
Battery    BAT0: charge: 31.0 Wh 51.6% condition: 60.0/60.0 Wh (100%)
           model: SMP DELL TP1GT61 status: Discharging
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-7500U (-MT-MCP-) arch: Kaby Lake rev.9 cache: 4096 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 11616
           clock speeds: max: 3500 MHz 1: 700 MHz 2: 700 MHz 3: 700 MHz 4: 700 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel HD Graphics 620 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: i915 Resolution: 3200x1800@59.98hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 18.0.5 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.17.14-041714-generic
Network:   Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath10k_pci bus-ID: 3a:00.0
           IF: wlp58s0 state: up mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Atheros usb-ID: 001-002
           IF: null-if-id state: N/A speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 512.1GB (3.8% used)
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 model: THNSN5512GPUK_NVMe_TOSHIBA_512GB size: 512.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 220G used: 5.9G (3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 14.00GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/nvme0n1p6
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 39.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 264 Uptime: 19 min Memory: 1499.5/15923.8MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: N/A
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.191) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Follow related 
[Ubuntu 18.04 crashes on resuming from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029405/ubuntu-18-04-crashes-on-resuming-from-suspend)

And nothing work, anyone had the same issue?

---

Finally today i use Ukuu to upgrade to 4.18.13 
So far seems to be working and try several times and different methods for suspendingn my system.

Here is the Line from suspend

```
Oct 10 19:52:51 talos systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Oct 10 19:52:51 talos systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Oct 10 19:52:51 talos systemd-sleep[2535]: Suspending system...
Oct 10 19:52:51 talos kernel: [   59.053826] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Oct 10 19:53:12 talos kernel: [   59.053828] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Oct 10 19:53:12 talos kernel: [   59.070315] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Oct 10 19:53:12 talos kernel: [   59.072350] OOM killer disabled.
Oct 10 19:53:12 talos kernel: [   59.072350] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Oct 10 19:53:12 talos kernel: [   59.073541] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Oct 10 19:53:12 talos kernel: [   59.098204] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: WARN: xHC save state timeout
```

Thank you, will keep posted, i still will like to know why this is happening.

### EDIT ##

System seems unstable this is the logs for an overnight suspend event.

```
Oct 10 23:22:37 talos firefox.desktop[2939]: [Child 3005, MediaPlayback #24] WARNING: Decoder=7f5a44bff880 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-IVlCbR/firefox-62.0.3+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3429
Oct 10 23:22:37 talos firefox.desktop[2939]: [Child 3005, MediaPlayback #25] WARNING: Decoder=7f5a44bff880 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-IVlCbR/firefox-62.0.3+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3429
Oct 10 23:22:37 talos firefox.desktop[2939]: [Child 3005, MediaPlayback #25] WARNING: Decoder=7f5a44bff880 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-IVlCbR/firefox-62.0.3+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3429
Oct 10 23:22:37 talos gnome-shell[1924]: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
Oct 10 23:22:39 talos systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Oct 10 23:22:39 talos systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Oct 10 23:22:39 talos systemd-sleep[2578]: Suspending system...
Oct 10 23:22:39 talos kernel: [12647.510128] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Oct 11 11:04:53 talos kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x8e, date = 2018-03-24
Oct 11 11:04:53 talos kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.18.13-041813-generic (kernel@gloin) (gcc version 8.2.0 (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1)) #201810100332 SMP Wed Oct 10 07:34:55 UTC 2018
Oct 11 11:04:53 talos kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.13-041813-generic root=UUID=86738284-8d9b-4c4c-ada4-3089924bd8ca ro nouveau.blacklist=1 quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Oct 11 11:04:53 talos kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Oct 11 11:04:53 talos kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Oct 11 11:04:53 talos kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
```

So it seems that is on and off , anyone with a new kernel that has the same problem.? Or maybe that can help me to debug its main issue?

EDIT 2

I updated the bios from Windows partition using latest driver from dell

https://www.dell.com/support/home/en/en/arbsdt1/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=rckdk

And use 4.18 Kernel (latest using ukuu). For now (24 hours and a few lid close events) seems to be stable on the wake and deep sleep.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `suspend.target`

Comment: ➜  ~ sudo systemctl status suspend.target
[sudo] password for : 
● suspend.target - Suspend
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/suspend.target; static; vendor preset: en
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
➜  ~

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is not a forum site.  Please, when you have additional information to add, please add it as an edit to your question, and not as an answer.  Reserve the Answers section for actual answers or solutions.

Comment: @user3483914 After updating the BIOS and using kernel 4.18 are you having any issues? I've been suffering through this suspend issue for more than a year (Dell Precision 7510) after trying all of the simple solutions and a few of the more complicated ones. I've made my computer unusable a few times by tinkering with it, but this issue is driving me nuts so I'm considering giving it one more shot.  Please let me know how things turned out!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem on my Dell XPS 15, and I unseccesfully tried  a lot of the possible solutions posted on the web. As a last shot I tried installing Kubuntu from scratch (not the kubuntu-desktop). Now I have the Nvidia driver running smoothly and resuming after suspending working like a charm. BTW now the kernel version is 4.18.0-15-generic. This might be key issue, as Ubuntu comes with 4.15 (if I recall well) and I already tried the kernel versios 4.19 to 4.20 without success.

Comment: As mentioned before installing Kubuntu from scratch solved the suspend/resume problem. Now I tried again with Ubuntu 18.04.2 and got the same problem after installing the nvidia driver, but this time I decided to switch to lightDM instead of gdm3. I used this command line sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 and selected lightdm and rebooted. Now suspend/resume works again, as well as my nvidia gtx 1050. SO, the problem seems to be related to GDM3 not with the driver or the kernel.

Comment: No, lightdm does not help. It freezes for me after 10-15 sec after resume.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you must downgrade your karnel version to 4.14.41 and it should work fine. Use ukuu for that

Comment: Try this already, now with 4.14.41 and 4.18.x is failing, tried also 4.17 4.15-36-37 ..any more ideas :)